# django deserialization error while generating fixtures

Tags: django, django-fixtures

I have generated test data from a tool called Mockaroo.
I have used csv2json.py script to convert the csv downloaded from Mockaroo to json format.
The json generated is being used as a fixture data to run unit tests.
I am facing deserializaion error for some of the fields since the fields are expecting some value to be present but I am leaving them blank.

Any help would be appreciable
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Replace all ' symbols with " using Pycharm or any other IDE, use https://jsonformatter.org/ to check your json data

Comment: I have the values in json in this format  "partner_id":" "

Comment: Can you send your .json file?

Comment: {
        "pk": "1097",
        "model": crmdata",
        "fields": {
            "area": "Indonesia",
            "country": "China",
            "region": "ID",
             "stage": "Open",
            "account_name": "ABCD",
            "account_id": 8718605,
            "account_owner": "Andreas W\u00fcck",
            "account_owner_id": "J460474",
            "account_type": "New",
            "partner_id": " ",
            "partner": " ",
        }
    }

Comment: I think, your schema is in the wrong format. Partner_id, is it str?